# How To Get Videos from Watch History and Watch Later Playlists by Youtube API (Android)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have looked YouTube Data API Revision History and noticed that the API is no longer support that Ids: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history

Is there a any way to get the videos from that playlists ?

Thanks,
Petros